# Tcl/Tk grab a window globally

Tags: global, tk-toolkit

My Tk application has a main window, when executing, new window arises to show the running progress. I want all the events (mouse, keyboard, etc) are directed to the progress window, so when program is runned, user cannot interact with the main window, and must wait until execution is done and progress window destroyed.

I tried using grab to handle this.

```
grab set .progress_window
```

But it doesn't work. The progress window still disappears when mouse clicked somewhere outside it. 
`grab set -global .progress_window` seems work but it block all the other windows running on my computer.

How to solve this problem? 
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You might need this too to keep it on top:

```
wm transient .progress_window .
```

Also, see how Tk itself creates modal dialogs.
There are some hoops to go through to get it fully right, e.g.:
https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/master/library/dialog.tcl